# How to type bold letter in math expression?

Tags: math-mode, bold, markdown, boldmath, boldsymbol

Actually, this is a markdown question. But I can't find a markdown community.

I want the letter "w" to be bold in the expression y(x, w). `$y(x, \boldsymbol{w})$` works. But the following parentheses become bold also. How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you please provide a complete example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`? Under normal circumstances the parentheses do not become bold. Or does markdown mean you are using something like MathJax?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat You guess it right. He can’t provide a MWE because he is not using LaTeX, but some math libraries like MathJax.

Comment: @Fractal Thanks! This is what I thought. Probably this question is off-topic then, right?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Not really, it only asks about math mode commands, no Markdown knowledge required. MadyYuvi’s answer is the correct answer, IMHO.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Ah, oh, sorry. My bad. I’m clearly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Happy New Year...

The tag `\mathbf{W}` may helps you

Answer (score -2):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
This program helps:

The equation is $y(x,\text{\textbf{w}})$
\end{document}
```

I think this also will work, but this considers 'w' as a text letter.

Comment: This does NOT work! What if I use a different font family for text mode (which is not uncommon)? There are many problems other than that! Please don’t confuse text mode and math mode!

Comment: By the way, I think your code is not even compilable. You need amsmath to use \text. (Not 100% sure if I am right, I’m not with my computer right now.)

Comment: I got it compiled. And amsmath is a common package that comes with Quickstart too right?

Comment: That depends on your editor. You may load it automatically, but not everyone does so. I just tested your code on my machine, it is not compilable. Error: `\text` is undefined.